# EF migration and $SolutionDir, .NetCore 2.2

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a strange error while trying to create initial migration in EF.

I have several projects - mostly .NetStandard.
Every project imports custom .targets file. It's just these lines at the top of .csproj file:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)Common.targets" />
```

Now, when I build my application everything works fine. When I run desktop project (that uses those .NetStandard dlls), everything works fine.

But when I try to add initial db migration, I'm getting errors like:

`D:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\Project.csproj: error MSB4019: Cannot find imported project file: "D:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\Common.targets" Make sure that the path in <Import> declaration is valid and the file exists.`

Note that I am using $(SolutionDir), so the valid path is: "D:\SolutionDir\Common.targets". So why does he search for this file in project dir?

Answer (score 1):

OK, it turnes out that $(SolutionDir) is only valid when compiling from VisualStudio. $(SolutionDir) does not exist when application is built using other ways (for example dotnet commands). So the only way is to create relative path from the project file.